# How can I send the content of a notification to Activity when the application is open?

Tags: java, android

I can send the content of the notification to the Activity when I click on the notification itself via Intent, by calling onNewIntent.

But how can I call onNewIntent through GcmListenerService?

I tried this:

```
Context.startActivity(new Intent (context, MainActivity.class));
```

But it leads to the crash,

Tell me, what should I do?

Comment: What do you want it to do? Send a message from a service to an activity on a running app? Then broadcast a message from the service and listen for that on the activity.

Comment: Please give a detailed description of what you want to do and also provide the stack trace of the crash.

Comment: Sorry for my English. I receive a number of new messages in the notification, I need to pass this parameter to the Activity.

Comment: And in the activation, I display this parameter in a separate window. I just need to call the public void in Activity from GcmListenerService.

Comment: What crash specifically?